# How would you set up this multilevel model?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have data at multiple levels and am trying to figure out how best to structure and analyze the data.

Participants completed five measurement occasions in each of four conditions (that is, it was a within-subjects study). There were also four participants per group.

So, should I do a four level model-- times/occasions (5) within conditions (4) within participants within groups? Or, should I do a three level model-- times/occasions (20, that is, 5 times x 4 conditions) within participants within groups, and then just have an extra predictor for the condition? I'm struggling with how best to make this work.

Comment: Given the very few numbers of units at the level of time, and level of conditions, I question the reliability of your estimates regardless of your choice of data hierarchy model.

Comment: Um, okay. So I just shouldn't analyze the data at all then? I'm not sure I understand what you are suggesting?

Comment: More or less, yes in terms of a multilevel model. Along the same lines of advice I would give to someone wanting advice for specifying a multiple regression (several predictors) but who had a sample size of, say, 9. Sometimes the data won't support the kinds of inference we would like to make, and the reliability of your level-specific variance estimates with tiny numbers of units may not be worth the while.